# how to convert sql date formate unix time stamp to date format as dd mm yy format?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have listing according to month year as may 2014 etc. I have take created date integer 11 in unixtime stamp format. how to compare date formate.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d-%m-%Y') AS Datetd
FROM `tbl_users_details` where DATE_FORMAT(created, '%m-%Y')='11-2011';
```

my created date save as '1357151400' this type.

but this is not working show only null value. not show record.

Comment: What database server are you using? This is not SQL-Server T-SQL syntax.

Comment: Looks like MySQL to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first try to get result from dual,

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TO_CHAR(unixts_to_date(1357151400), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'%d-%m-%Y')  FROM dual;
```

Try this Query

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TO_CHAR(unixts_to_date(1357151400), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'%d-%m-%Y') AS Datetd
 FROM `tbl_users_details` where DATE_FORMAT(TO_CHAR(unixts_to_date(1357151400), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS'), '%m-%Y') = '11-2011';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve de raw data string or timestamp from database and format it with PHP would be something like this:

```
SELECT date_field FROM `tbl_users_details` where something';
```

To format with PHP:

```
<?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['date_field'])); ?>
```

Comment: Adriano I have want to record find in sql not show in php format

Comment: Ok I gotta! probably as @user1153551 said might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have meet this answer for my problem and resolve problem.

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_users_details.created),'%Y-%m') AS Datetd
FROM `tbl_users_details` where DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(tbl_users_details.created),'%Y-%m')='2011-11';

Comment: where did `FROM_UNIXTIME` came from? it is not a recognized built-in function name for SQL 2016